# Difference between "source" and "."

Tags: bash

I am trying to learn Bash, and I came across `source` - very handy. However, when I tried to use `source` from scripts in different folders and created by different users, it suddenly didn't work. While searching online, I learned about `.` (a period). It's supposed to be a synonym of `source`, but I tried changing just for the sake of it. And it worked. So now I'm curious.

What is the difference between:

```
source
```

and

```
.
```

If really none, am I just imagining things?

Comment: "stop working", "suddenly didn't work" is a very imprecise description of what happened. Try to be more precise (Error message, unexpected result...)

Answer (score 5):

In `bash`, they are synonymous.
See https://askubuntu.com/questions/25488/what-is-the-difference-between-source-and-in-bash

About other flavors of shells, they may only have `.`, so `source` may be considered a [bashism](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#source).

(Which is kinda too bad, I find `source` more readable than `.`, though I suppose we wouldn't use `bash` for maximum readability.)